# Java 8 Casting Optional<Object> to long, int, String or Foo

Tags: java, option-type

I have this function and it returns an object because it has no ideas what the return could be. It could be in long, int, String, or Foo

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Optional<Object> getRequestByFieldName(String fieldName) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    Class<?> classA = instanceA.getClass();

    Method method = classA.getMethod("getAllFields");

    Object o =  method.invoke(instanceA);

    // I'm using protobuf to get the field value,
    // but a field could be missing because someone didn't send it
    // in that case I return an Optional Empty object
    Map<Descriptors.FieldDescriptor, Object> objectMap = (Map) o;

    Object fieldValue =  objectMap.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(fieldDescriptorObjectEntry -> {
                Descriptors.FieldDescriptor descriptor = fieldDescriptorObjectEntry.getKey();
                return descriptor.getName().equals(fieldName);
            })
            .findFirst().map(fieldDescriptorObjectEntry -> fieldDescriptorObjectEntry.getValue())
            .orElse(Optional.empty());

    return Optional.of(fieldValue);
}
```

How do I use this function to assign a variable to an int, long or Foo? This is what I currently have:

```
long someUid = (long) getRequestByFieldName("some_uid").orElse(0);
```

However, I keep getting this error if the field was missing:

```
java.util.Optional cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

Comment: I believe the issue could possibly be here: `orElse(Optional.empty())`. That potentially makes `fieldValue` an `Optional` which you then return by wrapping it in another `Optional`.

Comment: Most errors will tell you the line number. Please include this and indicate which line that is in your source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the field is not present you end up assigning `Optional.empty()` to the `fieldValue` variable.

```
Object fieldValue =  objectMap.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(fieldDescriptorObjectEntry -> {
            Descriptors.FieldDescriptor descriptor = fieldDescriptorObjectEntry.getKey();
            return descriptor.getName().equals(fieldName);
        })
        .findFirst().map(fieldDescriptorObjectEntry -> fieldDescriptorObjectEntry.getValue())
        .orElse(Optional.empty()); // ISSUE HERE
```

You then return with `return Optional.of(fieldValue)`. This means, when no field is found, you return an `Optional<Optional<?>>` so when doing the following:

```
long someUid = (long) getRequestByFieldName("some_uid").orElse(0);
```

The `orElse` bit is *never* called because the `Optional` is never empty. Instead, it holds an `Optional` which obviously can't be cast to `Long`. From your code, you should be able to simply return the result of `map`, like so:

```
return objectMap.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(fieldDescriptorObjectEntry -> {
            Descriptors.FieldDescriptor descriptor = fieldDescriptorObjectEntry.getKey();
            return descriptor.getName().equals(fieldName);
        })
        .findFirst()
        .map(fieldDescriptorObjectEntry -> fieldDescriptorObjectEntry.getValue());
```

Whether or not this completely solves the casting problem depends on how you determine what type of object the `Optional` holds.

Comment: Could be written as : `return objectMap.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(fieldDescriptorObjectEntry -> fieldDescriptorObjectEntry.getKey().getName().equals(fieldName))
                .findFirst().map(Map.Entry::getValue);`

Comment: @Slaw that was the issue. Thanks!